# Fadein effect on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to use the fade in/out effect of jQuery while loading a page? I don't want to have hidden div and I call the fadeIn() method to show those divs. I want the pages to load with such effect. Any solution to that?
So much appreciated !

Comment: What exactly would you consider the difference between the page loading with that effect vs. the page loading, then the effect running?

Comment: Sorry mate - that's not very clear.  You want to fade in when a page has loaded, but you don't want to use the fadeIn method - Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I second jvenema's comment, the "page" is really just a composition of all of the markup on the "page".  Why not wrap it all in a div and fade that in?

Comment: well, the jQuery `$(document).ready()` fires just after the DOM is ready (but images and such things are still loading). This might be what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Desription

You can set the `css` opacity attribute of the whole body  to `0` and then use `jQuery animate`.

#### I never thought about that, nice question! I have tested it and it works!

#### Sample

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="PathToJqueryJsFile" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("body").animate({ opacity : "1.0" });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="opacity:0"">
            Hello world
    </body>
</html>
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

### Update

Keep aware of hidding elements without checking the user has javascript enabled.

Comment: I strongly advise -not- doing it this way.  by putting display:none on your body you are essentially removing every single element on your page.  You may encounter trouble when trying to call other elements on the page. I suggest using my method below about visibility:hidden, that way the elements remain intact on the page.  When you do display:none, you remove the element from the flow of the page and it has to be re-added after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait for the page to load before you can execute code like that. Put it inside of this, and it will run as soon as possible:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // here

});
```

Comment: This doesn't consider image loading. He should use a preloader library and fade in on complete. I would recommend one but I've hated every jquery preloader I've used.

Comment: @Kai: I didn't see any mention of images up there. I read it as he wants to fade in a div /as/ the page loads.

Comment: I just made a div that contains my entire page elements, gave it an id, and set its display proprety to none, and called the fadeIn() method once the document is ready. THanks a lot guys, you're really fast and helpful !

Answer (score 1):

**I suggest NOT using fadeIn().  It could cause display inconsistency while elements & images are rendering**

I've created this jsFiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/Qrk6m/2/

I suggest using visibility:hidden ~ > visibility:visible CSS, and then using jQuery's animate() function

in CSS put:

```
#elementName{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

In JS Doc Ready Put:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#elementName').css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0},'slow');
});
```

Either way, you might want to refrain from display:none, and fadeIn().

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to accomplish a true fadeIn effect on load unless the div you are trying to fade is set to hidden by default.